# How to add 2nd Android activity in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity, google-provisioning-api

I am currently integrating a google tap&pay SDK in my Flutter app. My app `startActivityForResult` the native Google wallet Activity to add a card to wallet. Now wallet Activity wants to `startActivityForResult` another activity in my app to get the verification code.

Now since all Flutter apps based on single activity architecture. If I start a new instance of the same `Activity` in my flutter app the session gets invalidated for the previous instance. So I cannot work with multiple instances of the same Activity.

How can I add another `Activity` in my Flutter app which will could be launched and share the same Flutter engine?

The diagram looks something like this:

> A --> B --> C

1. A: Flutter Activity
2. B: Google Wallet Activity
3. C: Another Activity for getting verification code

Comment: @Muddassar the doc is about adding a flutter screen to existing android app. I want to add a new Activity to an existing Flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `flutter_isolate` package

[Flutter isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate)

Comment: How does this help? Please explain a little more

Answer (score -1):

To add a second Android activity in your Flutter app, you can follow these steps:

1. **Create a new Android Activity**: You can create a new Android activity in the android/app/src/main/java/your/package/name directory. This activity will be used to get the verification code.

```java
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class SecondActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

2. **Add the new Activity to AndroidManifest.xml**: You need to declare this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file which is located in android/app/src/main directory.

```xml
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Intent filters if any -->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

3. **Launch the new Activity from Flutter**: You can use `MethodChannel` to communicate between Flutter and native Android. Here is an example of how you can do this:

```dart
MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel('com.example/second_activity');
channel.invokeMethod('startSecondActivity');
```

And in your SecondActivity.java:

```java
new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "com.example/second_activity").setMethodCallHandler(
  new MethodCallHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
      if (call.method.equals("startSecondActivity")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    }
  });
```

Please note that you need to replace `com.example` with your own package name.

4. **Share the same FlutterEngine**: The primary API for adding multiple Flutter instances on both Android and iOS is based on a new `FlutterEngineGroup` class. This allows you to share the same Flutter engine across multiple activities.

> Remember, while this approach allows you to add a second activity to your Flutter app, it's generally recommended to use a single activity architecture in Flutter apps when possible. Multiple activities can lead to increased complexity and potential performance issues.